# Global list is appending nothing

Tags: python, list, global

```
answers = []

def search(visit_order, nodes_to_visit, distance):

    if len(nodes_to_visit) == 0:
        print visit_order
        answers.append(visit_order)
        return
    else:
        for node in nodes_to_visit:
            nodes_to_visit.remove(node)
            visit_order.append(node)
            search(visit_order, nodes_to_visit, 0)
            visit_order.remove(node)
            nodes_to_visit.append(node)

search([],nodes, 0)
print answers
```

I have a global list `answers` and a recursive function that goes through given `nodes_to_visit` list which will add `visit_order` to the `answers` list when there are no more `nodes_to_visit`.

When I print `Visit_order` right before appending, I get a correct value. However, when I print `answers`, I only get list of lists such as `[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]`. What is the problem?

For example, if I give search([],[1,2,3,4],0) as the input it is supposed to give me something like 
[[3, 1, 2, 4], [3, 1, 2, 4], [3, 1, 2, 4], [3, 1, 2, 4], [3, 1, 2, 4], [3, 1, 2, 4], [3, 1, 2, 4], [3, 1, 2, 4], [3, 1, 2, 4], [3, 1, 2, 4], [3, 1, 2, 4], [3, 1, 2, 4], [3, 1, 2, 4], [3, 1, 2, 4], [3, 1, 2, 4], [3, 1, 2, 4], [3, 1, 2, 4], [3, 1, 2, 4], [3, 1, 2, 4], [3, 1, 2, 4], [3, 1, 2, 4], [3, 1, 2, 4], [3, 1, 2, 4], [3, 1, 2, 4]] 
but it gives me [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []] instead.

Comment: send something in list 'search([1,2,3],nodes,0)

Comment: Code works fine when calling search with `search([1, 2, 3, 4], [], 0])`

Comment: Can't expect the nodes to stay in `visit_order` when you remove them from there immediately after the `search` call inside the loop.

Comment: Because you are appending the *same object* to answers. Check the output of `[id(e) for e in answers]` and you should see the same object ids. A quick fix is to append a *copy* by using `answers.append(list(visit_order))` or `answers.append(visit_order[:])`

Comment: While it's not the cause of your immediate issue (which juanpa.arrivillaga has diagnosed), there's another problem with your code that I suspect will result in you not getting the answers you expect. The problem is that you're modifying the `nodes_to_visit` list as you iterate on it. You're removing one item per iteration, and appending it back later on. Since that changes the list's order, the iteration is going to repeat some of the values, and skip over some of the others.

Comment: Thank you so much @Blckknght

Comment: @Blckknght Can you suggest how I may change this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is you are appending *the same object* to `answers` which you then empty. Check the output of `[id(e) for e in answers]` and you should see the same object ids. A quick fix is to append *a copy* by using `answers.append(list(visit_order))` or `answers.append(visit_order[:])`

```
In [4]: search([],[1,2,3,4],0)

In [5]: answers
Out[5]: 
[[],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 []]

In [6]: [id(e) for e in answers]
Out[6]: 
[140399731251400,
 140399731251400,
 140399731251400,
 140399731251400,
 140399731251400,
 140399731251400,
 140399731251400,
 140399731251400,
 140399731251400,
 140399731251400,
 140399731251400,
 140399731251400,
 140399731251400,
 140399731251400,
 140399731251400,
 140399731251400,
 140399731251400,
 140399731251400,
 140399731251400,
 140399731251400,
 140399731251400,
 140399731251400,
 140399731251400,
 140399731251400]

In [7]:
```

However, if I change the function to:

```
def search(visit_order, nodes_to_visit, distance):

    if len(nodes_to_visit) == 0:
        answers.append(visit_order[:])
        return
    else:
        for node in nodes_to_visit:
            nodes_to_visit.remove(node)
            visit_order.append(node)
            search(visit_order, nodes_to_visit, 0)
            visit_order.remove(node)
            nodes_to_visit.append(node)
```

Now...

```
In [8]: answers = []

In [9]: search([],[1,2,3,4],0)

In [10]: answers
Out[10]: 
[[1, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 3, 4, 2],
 [1, 3, 4, 2],
 [1, 3, 2, 4],
 [1, 3, 2, 4],
 [2, 4, 3, 1],
 [2, 4, 3, 1],
 [2, 3, 1, 4],
 [2, 3, 1, 4],
 [2, 3, 4, 1],
 [2, 3, 4, 1],
 [3, 1, 4, 2],
 [3, 1, 4, 2],
 [3, 4, 2, 1],
 [3, 4, 2, 1],
 [3, 4, 1, 2],
 [3, 4, 1, 2],
 [3, 2, 1, 4],
 [3, 2, 1, 4],
 [3, 1, 4, 2],
 [3, 1, 4, 2],
 [3, 1, 2, 4],
 [3, 1, 2, 4]]

In [11]:
```